# MySQL set NULL Query not always works

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `sent`='1', `taken`='1', `free`=NULL
WHERE `owner`='1' AND ISNULL(`sent`) AND !ISNULL(`free`);
```

Works, but set `free` to NULL not always works.
Any ideas? Thx

Comment: Are you sure all the other criteria of your `WHERE` statement are being met?

Comment: Sometimes all `free` set to NULL, sometimes not. I'm trying to recreate a situation...

Comment: `free` is only going to get set to `NULL` when `owner` is equal to `1` and `sent` is equal to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your triggers.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `sent`='1', `taken`='1', `free`=NULL
WHERE `owner`='1' AND `sent` is null AND `free` is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following query to check if it returns all the records you request:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `owner`='1' AND ISNULL(`sent`) AND !ISNULL(`free`);
```